# z-index of tooltip not working properly in bootstrap table header

Tags: html, css, z-index, react-bootstrap-table

[image]

I tried to add a tooltip in header of a Bootstrap table , but its some portion is hiding with the other column header,which is white in background, but our tooltip background color is different.

```
.tooltipe {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.tooltipe .tooltipetext {
  font-family: "Muli", sans-serif !important;
  display: none;
  width: 15em !important;
  max-height: 280px !important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 0.80rem !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1rem;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid #0093d0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2em;
  white-space: pre-line;
  position: absolute;
  top:10;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}
.tooltipe:hover .tooltipetext {
  display: block;
}
```

The above code is for tooltip, which `tooltipe` is the class for its content ,which will display on hover the `tooltip` class.

```
{
                dataField: 'aucr',
                text: (<span>AUC ratio<i
                className="fa fa-info-circle tooltipe ml-1"
                aria-hidden="true"
              >
                <span className="tooltipetext">Area Under the Curve ratio</span>
              </i>
            </span>),
                sort: true,
                filter: aucrFilter,
                headerStyle: {
                    minWidth: '160px',
                }
            },
```

This is how i added the column header with tooltip, i also made the column header sticky to make the headers freeze while scrolling vertically.

Comment: Please reproduce this in some live example here or jsfiddle, codesanbox etc

Comment: To force the tooltip in front, you can cheat and set the opacity of the tooltip to 99%. This may help if you want to do it properly - https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: Hi @chojnicki, basically i used the sticy in column header also , with some z-index of 2, even though the z-index of tooltip is high , its hiding behind the column